# Regex to extract URLs from href attribute based on username

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract all the links that comes from after a specific user, But my regex only grab one link:

HTML:

```
<div class="from_name">
   USERNAME
</div>
<div class="media_wrap clearfix">
   <div class="media clearfix pull_left media_photo">
      <div class="fill pull_left">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
         <a href="https://google.com</a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="text">
      <a href="https://yahoo.com</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Codes:

```
preg_match_all('/USERNAME[\s\S]*?href="(.*?)</', $data, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

//output, it's only caputre google.com :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => FullCapture

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://google.com
        )

)
```

Comment: How many links do you expect to have? Exactly 2 always? More than 2? Does the html structure change from one instance (user) to another?

Comment: While regex'es can be used sometimes to handle "minor" tasks involving HTML, your example seems to require a tool which is able to understand the structure of the HTML in order to extract the information properly.

Comment: Not always 2, maybe one or more

Comment: In that case, an HTML parser might be more helpful, with more accurate results.

Comment: for each, mate, for each

Comment: the regex that you are using doesn't catch anything at all, recheck it please.

Comment: i fixed it thanks, @vicent mate, how to foreach when there is only one item in array, read my post again, group1 captures only one href

Comment: @virolino HTML structure is same in all pages.

Comment: Can you have more than 1 user on the same page? Can you have links NOT associated to a user on that page?

Comment: @virolino if you familiar with telegram messanger, i have export chats history in my group and telegram gave me html files, my goal is find the username and exctract his messages which only contain url, According to what I saw, html structure is the same, here is the example for 3 users chat back together
https://pastebin.com/NmimuduB

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you use two regex? First to match the entire area with USERNAME and second to match the urls.

```
preg_match('/(?<=USERNAME).*(?<=href=").*?</s', $string, $matches);

preg_match_all('/(?<=href=").*?(?=<)/', $matches[0], $newMatches);

var_dump($newMatches);
```

This gives you:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "https://google.com"
    [1]=>
    string(17) "https://yahoo.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: @Diok No Problem! Please accept this answer as the solution. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the telegram messenger. Not I am almost sure that your problem cannot be solved (easily) with a regex. There are too many exceptions to the rule. So I will provide 2 alternatives:

1. Use a proper HTML parser, throw away what you so not need, capture the relevant information.
2. Use a hack

   - Parse the HTML

     - throw away everything which does not bring relevant information
     - you will end up with a list of names and links
   - if a name is followed by another name, delete it, since it has no links;
   - load whatever remains in an array, with the links associated to their repsective users.

After the parsing, you will have a structure similar with:

- name

  - link
  - link
- name      <--- you will delete this, before loading the data in an array
- name

  - link
- ...

You can do this parsing and deleting using string functions, or even regex'es.